# Mobile number should fetch network name and circle automatically - Ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, cordova, jquery-mobile, ionic-framework

I'm developing an ionic v1 app in which, when I'm typing the mobile number, the network name and circle name should get automatically updated in the dropdown as like the applications like PayTM, etc...

I'm having a database already in which networks have been split based on the first 4 digits of the mobile number. How to pass a request when a mobile number is being typed?

Please suggest some ideas to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use angular 1 ng-change

View.html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="mobilenumber" ng-change="updateotherfields()"  />
```

Controller.js

```
app.controller('yourCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.mobilenumber;
    $scope.updateotherfields = function(){

      if($scope.mobilenumber){
        //check the length

       if($scope.mobilenumber.length > 4){
          console.log($scope.mobilenumber);
         var firstfournumbers = $scope.mobilenumber.slice(0, 4);

       //now you have your fournumbers
      //Do you server code and then update the combobox Model

       }


}

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
 <form>
    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="number">
  </form>
  <button ng-click="submit(number)">Check</button>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.number;
    $scope.submit = function(number){
         console.log(number)
         var res = number.slice(0, 4);
         console.log(res)
    }

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

send 'res' value to server, search db table using that 4 digit value, get the detail of network